# Как определить самую большую цифру в числе?

Tags: java

```
public class start {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = 0;
        int k = 0;
        int[] m = new int[3];
        n = (int)(Math.random() * 899 + 100);
        System.out.print(n);
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            if (i < m.length - 1) {
                m[i] = n % 10;
                System.out.print(m[i] + " ");
            }
            else
                m[i] = n / 10;
            System.out.print(m[i] + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

Нужно сгенерировать трехзначное число и определить какая цифра в этом числе самая большая. До сравнения я даже не дошёл.

- почему мой рандом генерирует четырёхзначные числа, а не 100-999?
- попытался отделить от числа крайние правые числа с помощью `% 10`, а правую хотел получить обычным делением на 10, но что-то пошло не так.

Comment: Крайняя правая получается как остаток(!) от деления на 10. Какой диапазон чисел выдает random в жаве?

Comment: всё правильно, и 2 правых цифры с помощью этого отделить у меня получилось. вопрос что делать с третье и четвертой))

Comment: А кто вам мешает перевести число в строку и искать в ней цифры? :-)

Comment: мммм мешает то, что это задача из учебного курса, в теме ветвления, ну т.е кетч и свич, а до строк я ещё банально не дошёл. Должен быть вариант решения без использования строк:) Но если вы знаете хотя бы строчный вариант - напишите, буду изучать :)

Comment: Мне религия запрещает код за других писать :-) В общем, остаток от деления, деление и вычитание помогут вам даже в числовой версии.

Comment: может подскажете такую штуку: %10 я откидываю от числа правую цифру, как мне теперь сделать новое число без этой цифры ? ну т.е. есть например переменная n= 275. С помощью %10 мы откидываем 5, как мне теперь  сделать n=27, чтобы продолжить выполнять нужную мне задачу:)

Comment: Просто разделите на 10, элементарная арифметика.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Math.random()` возвращает число в диапазоне [0..1), т.е. код `(int)*(Math.random()*899+100)` возвращает целое число от 100 до 998; "четырехзначное" число у вас получается, т.к. вывод `n` "склеивается" с первым выводом цифры в цикле.

Для получения самой большой цифры в числе не нужен массив, достаточно просто хранить наибольшую на данный момент цифру (в начале цикла - 0).

Вы правильно получаете крайнюю правую (младший разряд) цифру взятием остатка от деления на 10. Потом вы делите на 10 все число, но результат этого деления нигде не используете. Вам нужно сохранять результат деления на 10, и брать младший разряд от него, пока в результате деления на 10 не получится 0.

Comment: хахахахах. спс мил человек, всё из-за отсутствия пробела))) боже какие ошибки глупые бывают:)  все сделал, вклеил в цикл откидывание  последней цифры от числа на каждом витке и понеслось))

Comment: @Ustin метод `println()` избавил бы вас от таких проблем со склеиванием. А форматирование (пробелы, отступы) сделало бы код более читабельным.